# Recovering a deleted text message on Android

Tags: sms

I accidentally deleted a very important text message that I received that included a link. I need to locate this text message. Is this possible on my Android Alcatel chatr wireless (cell provider) phone?

Comment: not without root access. depending on phone [model](https://www.chatrwireless.com/web/chatr.portal?_nfpb=true) chipset and/or android version there might be a workaround to create raw backup of userdata partition. SQLite browser may show deleted messages from mmssms.db (if database not flushed yet)

Comment: for example Alcatel 1 is mediatek chipset (mtk-su exploit or preloader mode) while Alcatel 1B is qualcomm chipset (edl mode). latter one most likely file-based-encryption which makes impossible to decrypt raw backup